# How to create a vector as a tensor object for different euclidean bases?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, vector-calculus, coordinate-transformation

The components of a tensor are always displayed with respect to one or multiple basis vectors.
For a tensor of rank 1, a vector, in 3D-euclidean space, we resort to three orthonormal basis vectors.

Now my question is, whether it is possible to define a vector `v` as a tensor, rather than just a list with fixed basis.
The wished functionality is to easily access its components with respect to any previously defined basis.

*As an example:*
Two basis systems are predefined with respect to a global basis: Basis `eS` with basis vectors `eS1,eS2,eS3` and basis `eB` with basis vectors `eB1,eB2,eB3`.
Then `v` is stored as a tensor object with respect to any known basis.

Now I would like to say "Give me the components of `v` with respect to Basis `eS` like
`v[BasiseS1eS2eS3] = {v_(eS1), v_(eS2), v_(eS3)}`
or with respect to `eB`
`v[BasiseB1eB2eB3] = {v_(eB1), v_(eB2), v_(eB3)}`.

Is there a functionality in MMA already implemented?

*Addendum: It would also be interesting to extend this concept to different coordinate system origins, like give me the components of the location vector `v` with respect to basis `eS` and origin `O`.*

*Addendum: I would like to avoid saving the same vector with different symbolic names for different basis systems, like `v_eB` `v_eS`.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We name "global" the built in basis. Assume then that 2 arbitrary basis are stored column wise in the following matrices:

```
Clear["Global`*", "ns`*"]
SeedRandom[1];
m1 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3, 3}];
m2 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3, 3}];
```

For safety, we create a separate names space "ns` to remember our bases and vectors. We define folowing associations:

```
ns`vecs = <||>;
ns`bas = <|global -> IdentityMatrix[3]|>;
```

To store a new basis, we define:

```
storeBas[name_, mat_] := AssociateTo[ns`bas, name -> Inverse[mat]];
```

Finally, to store a new tensor, we create a name that is not visible to the user and create a function, that returns a function. This returned function will remember the name of the tensor and returns the value of the tensor in the basis of choice:

```
makeTen[coord_] := 
 Module[{name = ns`Unique[]}, (AssociateTo[ns`vecs, name -> coord]; 
   Function[{basname}, ns`bas[basname] . ns`vecs[name]])
  ]
```

To make a test if everything works as intended, we first need to store our basis:

```
storeBas[bas1,m1];
storeBas[bas2,m2];
```

With the this we can now define some test tensor: {1,2,3} in the global basis by:

```
myten = makeTen[{1, 2, 3}];
```

and express it in the basis "global"  and "bas1" and "basis2":

```
myten[global]

{1, 2, 3}

myten[bas1]

{10.8218, 0.0276542, -10.0992}

myten[bas2]

1.20725, 1.99029, 3.34407}
```

To check if this correct, note that "bas.coordinates" should give the vector in the global basis:

```
m1 . myten[bas1]

{1., 2., 3.}

Addendum
```

To simplify, we may store the coordinates in the function itself, like:

```
makeTen[coord_] := Function[{basname}, ns`bas[basname] . coord]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this elegant approach. which does exactly what I wish it to do! So nice to learn new ways to use MMA

Comment: I added a simplification, we can actually store the coordinates in the function itself.

Comment: An extension for a symmetric tensor of second order, stored as a 3x3 array can be used as
`makeTen2[matrix3x3_] := 
 Module[{name = ns`Unique[]}, (AssociateTo[ns`vecs, name -> matrix3x3];
   Function[{basname}, 
    ns`bas[basname] . ns`vecs[name] . Transpose[ns`bas[basname]]])]`